# Heroku doesn't recognize rails api routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, routes

I have a rails api that works well on my local environment. I can even make all requests using Postman. However, when I deploy the app to heroku so I could consume the endpoints from my android app, I get 404 error with heroku log

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/v1/users").

But when, I run heroku rake routes, I find my routes as expected. What could I have done wrong?

routes from heroku after running `heroku rake routes`

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
        api_v1_users POST   /v1/users(.:format)            api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
         api_v1_user GET    /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PATCH  /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PUT    /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     DELETE /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
     api_v1_sessions POST   /v1/sessions(.:format)         api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
      api_v1_session DELETE /v1/sessions/:id(.:format)     api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}`
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json}, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    namespace :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post some more details like code of route, stack trace and maybe the controller ?

Comment: please post result of rake routes or your routes.rb

Comment: I suspect its something to do with routes, post the code of `route.rb` or output of `rake routes`

Comment: @sajan under my class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController I have this create action  def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
   render json: user, status: :created, location: [:api, :v1, user]
  else
   render json: {errors: user.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
 end  . However, it works perfectly on my local environment

Comment: @sajan my routes is  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json}, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    namespace :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end

Comment: Its better if you can edit and post it in question with better formatting.

Comment: @Deepak when I run heroku rake routes, I get      `api_v1_users POST   /v1/users(.:format)            api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
         api_v1_user GET    /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PATCH  /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PUT    /v1/users/:id(.:format)        api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     DELETE /v1/users/:id(.:format)`

Comment: The missing part of the puzzle is actually the request - can you show us the server log and tell us exactly how you setup the request in postman?

Comment: @max one of the requests I get when making a POST request through my android app is the `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/v1/users").` error i get. Maybe this has something to do with my routes i.e using subdomains

Comment: Yeah, my theory is that you are sending a request that does not satisfy the `subdomain` constraint. But you can help us help you by providing a full example so that we don't have to guess. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And please add the additional information by editing the question as you already been asked to do. Trust me people want to help and you will get better answers if you provide the correct information.

Comment: @max I am accessing my url with http://myappname.herokuapp.com/v1/users for the user's registration endpoint. My route is same as the one I have pasted. When I make a POST request via android, I get the ActionController routing error ` Started POST "/v1/users/" for 41.184.173.190 at 2016-10-19 16:23:19 +0000' and `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/v1/users"):`. I am thinking I should remove the subdomain part in my route. But my test is passing and I can sign up and in via Postman locally

Comment: ADD THE LOG FROM WHEN THE REQUEST STARTS TO THE QUESTION BODY. Press the edit button. This is not a discussion forum. This is Q&A. It is your responsibility to edit the question so that it contains the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks guys..I was able to fix this issue by removing the subdomain part. I really appreciate your effort. SO is great with loving people willing to help.